# What is the issue with this mysqli statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am not quite sure how to convert the mysql code here to a mysqli version. I keep getting the error like:

> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in....

Can you please help? thanks.

```
<?php

function the_user($username) {
    $myqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sometable");

    $username = sanitize($username);

    $user_query = mysqli_query($myqli, "SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'");

    return (mysql_result($user_query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;  

}
?>
```

Comment: remove quotes on column name 'username'=

Comment: replace single quotes around column names with backticks.

Answer (score 4):

The `'`s around the **column** names & **table** name. Should be -

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'
```

Or backticks.

Also mixing `mysql` & `mysqli`.

Comment: thanks but the same problem still exists.

Comment: yeah but what can I do about that? I mean that's the biggest problem here. actually.

Comment: @RaminRahimi Also pay attention to the last line about the mixing of methods. That seems to be the core problem that is causing the error message.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql` & `mysqli`. Fix that.

Comment: sure but is there a better way to write that last line maybe?

Comment: Yes. Follow the documentations for `mysqli`.

Comment: can you provide a link please? thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mysql_result` you should use `mysqli` like `mysqli_fetch_array`.
You should use :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_NUM);
return ($row[0] == 1) ? true : false;
```

Instead of:

```
return (mysql_result($user_query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Ofcourse don't forget to fix sql syntax as described in earlier answer:

```
$user_query = mysqli_query($myqli, "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")
```